# Conditional switch to file on startup

Tags: init-file, files, start-up

I'm using spacemacs and currently I'm using the following in my `user-config` to switch to the scratch buffer when emacs starts:

```
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(switch-to-buffer "*scratch*")
```

However, I want to adapt that code to open an org file instead. The issue is that I run the same config on 3 different computers and the location of the file is different for each:

- ~/Dropbox/myfile.org
- C:\Dropbox\myfile.org
- D:\Dropbox\myfile.org

How do I add some condition checking so that:

1. If I'm on OSX or Linux, load the org file from `~/Dropbox/myfile.org`
2. If I'm on Windows *and the file exists*, load it from `D:\Dropbox\myfile.org`
3. If I'm on Windows and #2 doesn't exist, load it from `C:\Dropbox\myfile.org`

My issue is differentiating between case 2 and 3. Case 1 can be handled by checking `system-type`, but on my desktop I have multiple hard drives so I keep Dropbox on `D:\`, but on my laptop I only have 1 SSD so Dropbox is on `C:\`, and need a way to figure out the correct path to the file on both Windows systems

Comment: Try `file-exists-p`.

Comment: Alternatively, create a symbolic link to the `Dropbox` directory on Windows.

Comment: Instead of comparing `system-type` you could use `system-name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if a file exists with `file-exists-p`. From its documentation:

> Return t if file FILENAME exists (whether or not you can read it.)

Note that this won't throw an error if you're, say, on Windows and trying to read `~/myfile.org`. So we can just loop over all the possible files and take the first one that exists:

```
(loop for filename in '("~/Dropbox/myfile.org" "C:\\Dropbox\\myfile.org" "D:\\Dropbox\\myfile.org")
      when (file-exists-p filename) collect filename into valid-files
      finally return (car valid-files))
```

This will return the first file that exists, which you can assign to a variable or open directly.